# Replace Lenovo Yoga cracked screen

Tags: laptop, touchscreen

I have a lenovo yoga 13.3" first gen touch screen laptop with cracked screen. LCD is working fine. I only need to replace the cracked screen which screwed up the digitizer. I'm using it by disabling the touch interface.

Can anyone help/redirect me with how to replace the screen?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Lenovo, they may have manuals available that detail replacement procedures.

Comment: I did. The cost would be upto $300 or more and that is why I'm contemplating on a DIY project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend contacting your countries [Lenovo Support Centre](http://support.lenovo.com/) as it may not cost a lot to have it replaced by them.

Failing that and if you are up to it, the Hardware Maintenance manual should have all the instructions you need to replace the digitizer.

[The instructions you'll need for removing and replacing the LCD assembly start on page 48 here.](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_yoga13_hmm_1st_edition_oct_2012_english.pdf) You will however need to go back as far as page 33 (1010 Keyboard) and work through to 1090 LCD unit.

**NOTE:** While Lenovo do freely release part replacement documents for their products, I would still recommend having the part replaced by a certified technician.